# What is "size"?

Tags: image, geometry, grid-layouts, size, rescale

When talking about concepts like `ItemSize`, `ImageSize`, `FontSize`, row/column height within a grid or any other size/scale functions, what units is Mathematica referring to? How are these related to the pixels on the default 100% notebook magnification?

The main reason I'm asking this is because I want to scale a program so that it fits any monitor it is rendered and displayed on. However, I don't really understand how size units are defined in Mathematica.

This must be naturally explained somewhere, but I couldn't find it and so any references are appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no universal unit in Mathematica. You will need to check the documentation for each size setting.

Commonly used units include:

- "Points" usually correspond to pixels on the screen (with Mathematica's default 72 dpi resolution) or printer's points in print. Examples: `ImageSize`, `Offset` coordinates, `FontSize`, etc.

  Sometimes, point sizes can be used in contexts where the default unit is something else through the [`Offset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Offset.html) wrapper.
- Plot coordinates use the coordinate system of graphics. This is how numbers are interpreted in graphics primitives. Some options, such as `PlotRangePadding` also use this.
- Scaled sizes/coordinates are relative to *some* larger object, which may differ from case to case. `Scaled` is relative to the plot area when used in graphics. It is relative to the notebook width when used in the `ImageSize` of a `Graphics`. `ImageScaled` is relative to the figure size. And so on.

  In most cases, scaled sizes must be explicitly indicated with the [`Scaled`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scaled.html) (or `ImageScaled`) wrapper and can be used in contexts where the default unit is something different.
- Units relative to the font size: this is often [ems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography)) for widths and line height for heights. Examples: `Spacings`, `ItemSize`, etc. These are typically used in the context of `Grid`/`Column`/`Row`.

Comment: Actually, points are 1/72nd of an inch.  The only time that maps 1:1 with pixels is on non-Retina Macs.

Comment: @ihojnicki The size of a "point" has changed so much and so often that it seems pointless. :) (E.g. a `pt` in TeX is 1/72.27 inch, which was known for a while as a printer's point, now an American point, as distinguished from the PostScript point, now called the desktop publishing point, which is 1/72 inch and denoted `bp` in TeX.)

Comment: Much like an Em, which used to be the width of an 'm'. Or a CSS pixel, which is not always a pixel.  Units are funny like that.

Comment: @ihojnicki So on Windows and Linux the default is not 1 pixel / 1 point anymore as on macOS? (Or 1 "logical pixel" if you like.)

Comment: @Szabolcs, correct.  That was part of the HiDPI update in 12.1.

Comment: @ihojnicki Can you please edit the post and make the necessary correction, or let me know how it works so I can do it myself? I can't test Linux/Windows right now. Is the pixel / point ratio `$ImageResolution / 72` then and `ImageSize` is still in points? (Assuming a numerical value of `$ImageResolution`)