# Scalable text in Graphics

Tags: graphics, function-construction, style, text

From my little experience, it seems impossible to scale a **text in `Graphics`**.

In other words, **text in `Graphics`** is not *scalable*.

Only for this post, we define the word *scalable*, to be

> width/height change when we mouse-click its surrounding frame(or similar thing) and move back and forth. The quality of the result should be similar to that of common `Graphics` primitives like `Circle`, `BezierCurve`, etc.

Rasterizing the text in the `Graphics` isn't allowed since it is of a low quality.

Below is a typical example.

[image]

`Circle[]` is scalable, but
`Style[Text[x^2 + y^2 < 1, {0, 0}], FontSize -> 50]` is not scalable.

Is there a way to create scalable **text in `Graphics`** ?
If I had to bet, I'd bet that there isn't such method without `Dynamic`(or similar things).
But, I don't have much experience with `Graphics`, so I can't jump to conclusions.

Is there an orthodox method to create *scalable* **text in `Graphics`** ?

If you think there isn't, comment is welcome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/250712/12

Comment: Have you tried a `Scaled` expression in your `FontSize` directive, instead of an explicit fixed size?

Comment: @Szabolcs : Thank you, it is related but can't go any further from there. Do you think orthodox method is impossible?

Comment: @MacroB : No, `Scaled` is new to me. Could you write an example code ?

Comment: `Graphics[Text[Style["Foobar", FontSize -> Scaled[1/4]], {0, 0}]]`. However, for publication figures, it's much better to create them with the final size in mind. Rescaling is what leads to ugly figures with 1 cm large letters, or 2 mm unreadably small ones. What I normally do is target a certain font size and a certain panel size, e.g. `cm = 72/2.54; Graphics[Text["Foobar", {0, 0}], BaseStyle -> 12,  Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 8 cm]`

Comment: Thank you! It is working! It seems to be too hard to find in the document compared to its importance. You can write it as an answer if you want to be accepted.

Comment: @imidak `Scaled` is [the second result in a search](https://reference.wolfram.com/search/?q=scalable) of the documentation for "scalable", which I took from your question.  That doesn't seem exactly hidden.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think to look it up with scalable, and It was hard to find right example specific to the *text* in `Graphics`.